# pip target directory on CentOS6 with scl

Tags: python, pip, centos6

I am trying to configure `pip` target path on CentOS by all known methods to no avail. I have no su rights. What I did:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/tools/.usr/py2/lib
echo $PYTHONPATH
# returns $HOME/tools/.usr/py2/lib
```

content of `~/.pydistutils.cfg`:

```
[install]
install_scripts = $HOME/tools/.usr/py2/scripts
install_data = $HOME/tools/.usr/py2/data
install_lib = $HOME/tools/.usr/py2/lib
```

Running

```
scl enable python27 '$HOME/tools/.usr/py2/scripts/pip install --install-option="--home=$HOME/tools/.usr/py2/lib" ipython'
```

results in warnings like this:

```
Target directory $HOME/tools/.usr/py3/lib/pathlib2.py already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
```

I.e. it has uses some other path file or variable than all listed above and believes that target is `$HOME/tools/.usr/py3/lib`. Why is it so and how to force it to my `$PYTHONPATH`?

Another try:

```
scl enable python27 '$HOME/tools/.usr/py2/scripts/pip install --install-option="--prefix=/ye/netapp/jimmie.ye/tools/.usr/py2/lib" --upgrade pip'
$HOME/tools/.usr/py2/lib/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py:180: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.1.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pip
  Running setup.py install for pip ... error
    Complete output from command /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/scrape/dlituiev/pip-build-pGEJ7L/pip/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /scrape/dlituiev/pip-SScyQc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --prefix=/ye/netapp/jimmie.ye/tools/.usr/py2/lib --home=/scrape/dlituiev/tmps67g2R:
    running install
    error: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/scrape/pip-build-pGEJ7L/pip/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /scrape/dlituiev/pip-SScyQc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --prefix=$HOME/tools/.usr/py2/lib --home=/scrape/tmps67g2R" failed with error code 1 in /scrape/pip-build-pGEJ7L/pip/
```

all `$HOME` are spelled in full in original commands and errors.

Comment: What is the shebang (first line starting with `#!`) of `$HOME/tools/.usr/py2/scripts/pip`?

Comment: Also, check for a `~/.pip/pip.conf` configuration file - if that exists, it could be affecting things.

Comment: You could also try running pip as a Python module rather than an explicit path: `scl enable python27 'python -m pip install ...'`

Comment: Thank you Thomas! Is there a way to stop pip from deleting/ moving around existing packages. It just clears to the ground my package path, happy that I have a backup. This is extremely annoying...

Comment: I'm not sure why it would do that - it will remove packages it's trying to upgrade, but it shouldn't be deleting anything else.

Comment: It looks like it is because it takes stuff which is in `.pydistutils.cfg` path and moves it to the `.pip/pip.conf` path. uhh. submitted an issue to pypa. Wish people who design installation tools were aware of different python versions.

Comment: Have you been able to get it to do what you need? I've subscribed to your [pip issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3658), still puzzled what it's doing there.

Comment: BTW, you might also be interested in this blog post on using virtualenvs with SCL: http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/02/27/using-pythons-virtualenv-with-rhscl/

Comment: I was able to patch make it work for now. Removed `.pydistutils.cfg` and set `.pip/pip.conf`.